# Displaying images in select2 based on data attributes on options

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to do something with Select2 like the [templating example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) but I'm not using a predefined set of images so need to modify it somewhat.

I thought I could add the path to the image I want to display with a data attribute on each option and then instead of `element.value` I could use `element.attr('data-thumb')` but when I do that I get *element.attr is not a function*

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="A" data-thumb="a.jpg">A</option>
  <option value="B" data-thumb="b.jpg">B</option>
  <option value="C" data-thumb="c.jpg">C</option>  
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function productStyles(selection) {
    if (!selection.id) { return selection.text; }
    var $selection = $(
      '<img src="' + selection.element.attr('data-thumb')+ '"> ' + selection.text
    );
    return $selection;
};

$('.img-changer').select2({
    templateResult: productStyles
});
```

Is it possible to access data attributes using `.element` or do I need another approach and if so, what would that be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out what I needed was `var thumb = $(selection.element).data('thumb')`.

```
function productStyles(selection) {
  if (!selection.id) { return selection.text; }
    var thumb = $(selection.element).data('thumb');
    if(!thumb){
      return selection.text;
    } else {
      var $selection = $(
    '<img src="' + thumb + '" alt=""><span class="img-changer-text">' + $(selection.element).text() + '</span>'
  );
  return $selection;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option class="img class" value=""></option>    

function formatSelect2(o) {
if (!o.id)
    return o.text;
else
    return $("<span><i class='" + $(o.element).attr("class") + "'></i> " + o.text + "</span>"); }     

$('#Category-Add').select2({
        width: '100%',
        templateResult: formatSelect2,
        templateSelection: formatSelect2,
        theme: "classic"
    });
```